# How to include bar with NAs in geom_histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, na

I am trying to create a histogram of a continuous variable (1-10) with a bar a little to the side that says how many NAs are in the vector. I am using `geom_histogram()` from `ggplot2`. Here is an example:

```
v <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA))

ggplot(v, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]

I have looked through the features of the function but there doesn't seem to be a way to inlcude NAs and haven't found an elegant way of doing it from other questions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't if it is a perfect solution but you can get the count of NA by using `dplyr` before plotting your data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
v %>% group_by(x) %>% count(x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(x), y  = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This does work, although my measure goes up to 10, and when it's classed as a factor it goes `1 10 2 3 ...`. How could I solve this?

Comment: You can use `scale_x_discrete(limits = c(1:10,NA))` in the ggplot. However,  in my example, even if I had several `10` values in `v`, I do not get the same issue